# Emulating Eclipse execution environment

Tags: eclipse, ide

Is there a way to:

1. Exactly reproduce the Eclipse IDE execution environment, outside the IDE?
2. Find out exactly which commands are executed behind the scenes when an Eclipse option is invoked, and with what command line options?

There are many instances (e.g. [this Stackoverflow post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868103/non-default-testng-file-ignored-during-command-line-execution-dsurefire)) where I can get something running fine within the Eclipse IDE environment but I run into problems when I try equivalent commands from the OS shell.  Obviously there is something right about the Eclipse IDE environment, and something wrong with my environment.

I am hoping that if I can largely emulate the Eclipse execution environment in the OS command shell window, these inconsistencies that I am observing will go away.

---

Following up on @greg-449's response,  '**Show Command Line**' turned out to be more obscure than I had expected.  Hopefully the following pictures will help:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is a 'Show Command Line' button on the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog for when you Run something. Other things may just be calling APIs rather than running any command.

Comment: What is 'obscure' about that command line? That is a fairly typical Java command when you aren't using a jar.